# Populating mysql database with grants from mysql dump

Tags: database, mysql, mysqlimport

I've taken a mysql dump of a database using the command:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --all-databases --flush-privileges -h HOST -u USER -p PASSWORD
```

I purposefully used the `--all-databases` flag to make sure that I got all the users I had created and the permissions they had granted. But when I run the import to a new database as the root user, I get this error: `Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'mysql'`

Is there a different way to copy over users and permissions from one database to another?

Answer (score 0):

I use a SHOW GRANTS statement to get the privileges, for example:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR foo@'%'
```

Which returns something like this:

```
Grants for foo@%                                                                                                                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'foo'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*B3CD------------------------------------'
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, EXECUTE ON `db`.* TO 'foo'@'%'
GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`proc` TO 'foo'@'%'
```

I can easily take the output, add the semicolon statement terminators, make any other necessary modifications, and execute them on another database.

And just repeat that for whichever users I need to migrate.

Comment: I guess that works for this. but it's a bit of a pain. is there a more streamlined approach? Thanks!

Comment: There's probably a more streamlined approach. This is just how I do it. As far as taking a mysqldump of the mysql database, and then attempting to import that wholesale into a different database... that's not something I would do, because there's a *lot* of tables in the mysql db other than user, db and tables_priv. And I've not seen (or looked for) any instructions/warnings about doing something like that. As far as the actual error message, I expect that's because the user `root@'%'` isn't defined or wrong password. DML changes to the privileges tables need FLUSH PRIVILEGES to be effective.